# My method to $\int^1_0 \log^{2020}x dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

**Question.** Solve: $$\int^1_0 \log^{2020}x dx$$

**Attempt.** Now I don't want any other alternative as I know there are many, I just want to know about my method: let $u=\log^{2020}x$ so that $du=2020\log^{2019}\frac{1}{x}dx$ this cancels out to a single log like the following: $$\frac{1}{2020}\int^0_{+\infty}\sqrt[2020]{u}e^{\sqrt[2020]{u}}du$$ since $\log x=\sqrt[2020]{u}$ and $x=e^{\sqrt[2020]{x}}$. Then we do a final one, $t=\sqrt[2020]{u}$ so that $dt=\frac{1}{2020}u^{-\frac{2019}{2020}}du$ hence $u=t^{2020}$ and flipping the integral to have it negative, and since the bounds don't change, we have: $$-\int^{+\infty}_0 t^{2020}e^t dt$$ and now here comes where I'm unsure, I didn't know what to do so I decided to go with the integration by parts 2020 times? As crazy as it sounds, I'd expect so from a Berkeley competition. I gave it a try:

Excluding the first term which is positive, leaving that negative out I'm pretty sure we get this?: $$-\left[t^{2020}e^t-t^{2019}e^t-t^{2018}e^t-\dots-te^t-e^t\right]^{+\infty}_0$$ and then this? $$\lim_{t\to\infty}(-t^{2020}e^t+\sum^{2019}_{k=0}e^t t^k)-1$$ (the last 1 there is because if we plug 0 we get 1 on the last term).

Again, I'm unsure whether this is even possible, but yeah, I'm stuck there and I wonder if:

- What I have done until there is correct?
- Is it possible to do it 2020 times as I did?
- Is it possible to continue from this point? Not from another point, I know other alternative methods.

Comment: It seems like there are some minus signs missing. Calculate $\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t}dt$ for $n=0,1,2,3\dots$ and see if you find a pattern which you can prove using e.g. induction

Comment: I didn't read carefully the whole thing, but assuming $\log^{2020}(x)$ means $(\log(x))^{2020}$ then the first $du$ should be $du= \frac{2020}{x} \log^{2019}(x) dx$... maybe that's just a typo?

Comment: @leoli1 indeed, the final integral in $t$ should have the negative infinity as upper limit if gamma function is to be used. However, I don't see how that can be proved if we go by OP's method, since the 2020$^{th}$ root of a number, if real, can be both positive and negative. The positive limit which OP has taken clearly doesn't converge, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is useful to know [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), then realize that substituting

$$\log x=-u$$

that is

$$x=e^{-u}$$

and

$$dx=-e^{-u}du$$

your integral becomes

$$\int_0^{+\infty}u^{2020}e^{-u}du=\Gamma(2021)=2020!$$

Comment: I mentioned no other methods but the final part serves me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In general

$$\int_0^1 \ln^n x\>dx=\left( \frac{d^n}{dx^n} \int_0^1 x^a\>dx\right)_{a=0}= \left(
\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \frac{1}{a+1}\right)_{a=0}=(-1)^nn!
$$

Answer (score 2):

if you mean $\log^{2020}=(\log)^{2020}$ it's easy to solve that .just put $\log(x)=u\implies dx=e^udu $ so we find :

$\int_0^1\log^n(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^0 u^ne^udu=(-1)^n n!$    then we find for  $n=2020$

$\int_0^1\log^{2020}dx=2020!$